# Lucene - Validate completeness of index

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, indexing, lucene

We are using Lucene 5.5.5 in order to allow full text search over our database content. We build the index after a database migration and make use of the near-real-time indexmanager in order to keep the index up-to-date. However, sometimes it may happen that the server is killed before the indexmanager could commit the index-entries that it still holds in memory.

In order to avoid having to always rebuild the index on server-startup, since it's quite slow, I was wondering whether the index could be checked for completion. I know there's the `CheckIndex`-Utility, but as far as I understood it can only check whether an index is broken, but not if it's complete.

Another option could be an indexer that doesn't fully rebuild but completes an already existing index.

What would be the best way to go about this? My goal is to waste as little time as possible on startup and have a complete index.

An obvious solution would be to not use the near-real-time indexmanager anymore I guess, but for now, I'd like to not consider that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, **near-real-time** indexmanager buffers the modifications in a memory and as far as i know currently it's not possible to verify the completeness of index flushing.

So the solutions could be:

1. switch to **directory-based** indexmanager. (drawback: worse performance comparing to near-real-time indexmanager )
2. use `healthcheck` service that will check state of your app and update a flag `isServerForciblyClosed` in the db and if it's `true` then rebuild index on next startup. This service should be turned off in case of planned shutdown.
3. create your own `CustomIndexManager` implementation extending built-in classes or completly from scratch implementing `Indexmanager` interface

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "1)". The index manager already is directory based? Both near-real-time and the default. Or am I missunderstanding the term?

Comment: look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.2/reference/en-US/html/search-configuration.html#configuration-indexmanager

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's what I meant. That's what we used before NRT, which we stopped usign due to performance impacts. Obviously that would solve the data inconsistency problem :D However, I was trying to find the best of both worlds. Maybe approach "2)" would be somewhat best. Is it possible to find out whether the NRT has already flushed or even force flush if possible?

Comment: No, as far as i know it's not possible. But you could create your own custom implementation `hibernate.search.[default|<indexname>].indexmanager = my.corp.myapp.CustomIndexManager`

Comment: NRT has nothing to do with IndexWriter, but rather with re-opening of the IndexSearcher/Reader.

Comment: @Mike Adamenko I assume making your own Indexmanager would be quite a lot of work and we are a ver small team with too little time.

Comment: @injecteer so? I am not sure what to make of that information.